# Error while deploying items with more than one component

Tags: jss

When I create 2 components in the YML files I get the following error:

> ManagedPoolThread #11 09:09:12 INFO  [JSS] - Creating route-level
> datasource folder (RouteLevelDatasourceStrategy) ManagedPoolThread #11
> 09:09:12 INFO  [JSS] - Ensuring item path:
> /sitecore/content/spv-no/lane/boliglaan/home/produkt/Page Components
> ManagedPoolThread #11 09:09:12 ERROR [JSS] - Exception thrown while
> importing JSS app Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message:
> The ID {97944C4D-495A-5845-8688-E695A7378EA3} has been used more than
> once during import. This likely means two imported items have the same
> id value, or two items of the same type (e.g. templates) share the
> same name. Details: path leaf item Page Components in path
> /sitecore/content/spv-no/lane/boliglaan/home/produkt/Page Components,
> path leaf item Page Components in path
> /sitecore/content/spv-no/lane/boliglaan/home/produkt/Page Components
> Source: Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices    at
> Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Data.IdManager.AssertIdIsUnused(ID
> id, String idUsageDescription)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I can see the error it says - The ID {97944C4D-495A-5845-8688-E695A7378EA3} has been used more than once during import. This likely means two imported items have the same id value or two items of the same type (e.g. templates) share the same name. That means you are using same name or id.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal as you can see from the error, it's the "Page Components" folder that JSS import tries to create twice with the same ID. So I have no items with the same name or ID and I have no templates that share a name. It does not matter witch 2 components I try to add to a page, as soon as a page has 2 components, this error occurs.